# Themes conflicts and overrides my WordPress Support widget Plugin styles

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, css

The front end of the widget plugin has the widget launcher and once opened, it shows the actual widget with its elements. it has lots of styling issues which are 100% from whichever theme is currently active on the site. most of the styles get influenced and this is overridden by whichever theme is running and thus add its own styles to my widget. how can I make the widget 100% independent and only show its own styles without any interference from themes?

Comment: What widget plugin are you referring to?

Comment: my own. it's a help and support widget that shows help articles and also comes with a form.

Answer (score 0):

You should always **prefix everything** when creating your own plugin. Also try to avoid generic classes like `.col` and `.container`. If you don't, that's a recipe for disaster.

So use `.yourpluginprefix_container` instead of just `.container`.